# why does the IF statement being skipped?

Tags: android, android-activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button scan_btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
        scan_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
        final Activity activity = this;
        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result.getContents() != null) {
            if(result.getContents().equals("Electronics A1")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Hi all, currently doing a project for my school.
now im having problems with the program.

```
 if(result.getContents() != null) {
            if(result.getContents().equals("Electronics A1")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

curently this if stament is being ignored by the app.
the purpose of the statement is when i scan a specific qr code it will move to a new activity or do something.

yesterday the statement was working but suddenly today it wont work......

can you guys help me?
currently new to android studio

Comment: Put a break point on each line. See what condition is not met.

Comment: if statement is ignored means it always returns false right ? if not then what do you mean ? Also please specify which if statement is ignored

Comment: this line is ignored    if(result.getContents().equals("Electronics A1")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Put this Debug.Log(result.getContents()); before your if and see what the contents is. Debugging is really important in programming

Comment: Lol guys thanks for your help. Its my fault as my QR code has an error